# How to move Azure Resource group from one azure account to another azure account?

Tags: azure

I want to move azure resource group from one azure account to otherazure account. Can any one help me how to move this to other account?

Comment: how is this suitable for stack overflow?

Comment: do you mean account from different directories?

Comment: Do you mean subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your question is correct. You're intending to move Resource Group from one account/subscription to another Azure Subscription/owner. If this is the case, you can move **resources** from a source group to a target group in a different subscription.

There are some important steps to do before moving a resource. By verifying these conditions, you can avoid errors. Currently, not all resources in Azure support move. For a list of resources that support move, see [Move operation support for resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources).

Kindly verfiy and validate the move as outlined in this document- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#validate-move before initiating the move process.

**Note:** Moving a resource only moves it to a new resource group or subscription. It doesn't change the location of the resource.

Comment: A subscription is not an azure account. I can't explain it more than that you can't move a subscription into another Azure AD until that Azure AD has an Azure account.